# Updating customer's address works in Observer.php, fails in custom PHP file

Tags: php, sql, ajax, magento

I've connected an AJAX call to event on changing customer's address in Checkout. It is supposed to update 1 field in customer's address.

```
require('../../../../Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$newContactologyClientId = $_POST['contactologyClientId'];

$customerDefaultAddressId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping();
$customerAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$customerAddress = $customerAddress->load($customerDefaultAddressId); 

$_new_address = array (
    'contactology_client_id' => "$newContactologyClientId"
    );

$customerAddress->addData($_new_address);
$customerAddress->implodeStreetAddress()->save();
```

On JavaScript side everything is ok, so I won't include that here. The posted code responsible for database update works when fired up in my module's Observer.php on Magento event (`sales_quote_save_after`), but when I run it via AJAX I get error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: 
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`mag6`.`customer_address_entity`, 
CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_PARENT_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) 
ON DELETE CAS)' in C:\(...)\Pdo.php:228
```

The line which causes the error is the last one naturally:

```
$customerAddress->implodeStreetAddress()->save();
```

So I reckon that if the database operation works in `Observer.php` and it doesn't in my custom `onCheckoutAddressEdit.php`, it is because including `Mage:app()` is not enough and I need to require additional classes, but no idea which one.

Comment: I was wrong - it was the case of NULL `customerDefaultAddressId`, now I got `implodeStreetAddress()->save()` working. Well, at least it doesn't throw errors, but it won't make changes to database either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are missing:

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Looking at the code, it looks like `$customerDefaultAddressId` returns `NULL`, so the customer session must not be instatiated properly.